# Header and Footer won't stay in place on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have a refreshable list (with Iscroll) on my android app. 
Somehow if I reload the list:

```
myScroll.destroy();
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
    useTransform : false,
    hScroll: false
});
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 'loaded', false);
```

The header and footer disappear at scroll (sometimes they do, sometimes they don't). 
Is there any way to make sure they will never ever scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following CSS to keep my header in place on Android:

```
.header {
text-align: center;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#999));
height: 58px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem by adding: <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" /> , at the end that was the only solution that worked.